# Setting margin to 0 does nothing

Tags: html, css

I am looking in the chrome developer console and see that when I highlight over the md-sidenav node the red highlighting indicates a massive right margin. This also happens when I hover over margin in the computed styles panel. I want to remove this margin so I can place things directly next to the border of the md-sidenav node. But when I set margin: 0, nothing happens. 
[image]

Comment: The width is fixed, I suppose, and the "align" is left. So you can place things next to it. But it won't remove the margin.

Answer (score 2):

md-sidenav* has a defined width - try

```
width: 100%
```

Comment: I gave a width: 100% to md-sidenav but did not change anything.

Comment: mind the mediaqueries: "min-width: 600px" and "max-width: 456px"